# Number Board Program doesn't place hyphens correctly in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, parameter-passing

We're supposed to create a number board whereby a user is allowed to select a number for instance, number 5 and one of the number 5's in the board will be clearly indicated as selected with a hyphen above and below it.

Problem now is: No matter what I try the hyphens refuse to move to the right spot.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>

#define HEIGHT 9
#define WIDTH 8


void board(char array[HEIGHT][WIDTH])
{    
    int x,y,i,j,score,steps = 0;

/****BORDER CREATION*/          
    for (i = 0; i < WIDTH+4; i ++)
        printf("# ");    
    printf("\n");

    for(y=0;y<WIDTH+1;y++)
    {
       printf("\n");    
       printf("# ");

       for(x=0;x<HEIGHT+1;x++)
         {              
          printf("%c ",array[y][x]);          
         }
       printf("# ");
    printf("\n\n");                
    }

    for (i = 0; i < WIDTH+4; i ++)
    printf("# ");    
    printf("\n");       
/****BORDER CREATION*/      
}


void instruc(char *name, int *steps, int *selected)
{       
    /*User record & score header*/      
    printf("\n-----Hello %s! Let's see what you can do------\n",name);      
    printf("----------WELCOME TO NUMBER CONNECT----------\n");
    printf("----------PREVIOUS PLAYERS' RECORDS----------\n");
    printf("----------Name: %s   Score(Steps): %i--\n\n",name,*steps);

    printf("\nYour score: %i",*steps);
    printf("\nNumber %i is currently selected",*selected);

    printf("\n\nAction Keys: ");
    printf("\nPush 'U' to move UP"); 
    printf("\nPush 'D' to move DOWN");
    printf("\nPush 'L' to move LEFT");
    printf("\nPush 'R' to move RIGHT");

    printf("\nPush 'X' to REMOVE path\n");
    printf("\nTo select a new number, press digits from 1 to 7\n");
    printf("\nPush 'q' or 'Q' to QUIT\n\n");    
}


void select(int *selected,char array[HEIGHT][WIDTH])
{    
    int i,j,x; 

    printf("\nPlease select a number (1-8): ");  
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%i",selected);
    /*POINTER TYPE CONVERTION FAIL 
    selected = (char)*selected;*/

    /*ASCII CHARACTER ATTEMPT FAIL 
    if (*selected == 1){
    *selected = 1;
    }
    else if (*selected == 2){
    *selected = 2;}
    else if (*selected == 3){
    *selected = 3;}
    else if (*selected == 52){
    *selected = 4;}
    else if (*selected == 53){
    *selected = 5;}
    else if (*selected == 54){
    *selected = 6;}
    else if (*selected == 55){
    *selected = 7;}
    else if (*selected == 56){
    *selected = 8;}
    else{ 
    printf("Non-Numeric Input not allowed");}*/

    printf("\nNumber Selected: %i",*selected);

/*To indicate selected number with hyphens (denoted by 45)*/        
    for (i = 0; i < WIDTH+1;i++)
    {
        for (j =0; j < HEIGHT+1; j++){          
            if (array[i][j] == *selected){              
                array[i-1][j] = 45;
                array[i+1][j] = 45;         
            }                   
        }
    } 
    printf("\nPosition of i:  %i ",i);
    printf("Position of j:  %i\n\n",j);       
}


void assign(char array[HEIGHT][WIDTH], int *selected)
{    
    int i,j;
    /*int rr,rrr;
    int x = 0;
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < WIDTH+3;i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++){           
            x = (rand()%8+1)+48;
            array[i][j] = x;                             
        }
    } 

    for (i = 0; i < WIDTH+3;i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < HEIGHT+3; j++){     
            rr = rand()%WIDTH;
            rrr = rand()%HEIGHT;
            x= 32;
            array[rr][rrr] = x;    
        }        
    }        
    printf("\n");*/     

/*To blank our everything that is not a symbol*/        
    array[0][1] = 49;
    array[0][7] = 49;

    array[5][9] = 50;
    array[6][1] = 50;

    array[1][4] = 51;
    array[5][7] = 51;

    array[7][2] = 52;
    array[5][5] = 52;

    array[3][3] = 53;
    array[1][1] = 53;

    array[7][3] = 54;
    array[6][2] = 54;

    array[3][7] = 55;
    array[7][6] = 55;

    array[2][4] = 56;
    array[4][4] = 56;

    for (i = 0; i < WIDTH+4;i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < HEIGHT+4; j++){

            if ((array[i][j] != 49) && (array[i][j] != 50) && (array[i][j] != 51) && 
        (array[i][j] != 52) &&  (array[i][j] != 53) &&  (array[i][j] != 54) &&  (array[i][j] != 55) &&
        (array[i][j] != 56)){           
                array[i][j] = 32;
            }
        }
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    int i,j,x,y,score = 0,steps = 0,result = 0,selected=0;
    char array[HEIGHT][WIDTH],name[20];

    printf("Please Input Name: ");
    scanf("%s",&name);

    instruc(name,&steps,&selected);

    assign(array,&selected);

    board(array);  
    select(&selected,array);
    board(array); 

    return 0;       
}
```

Comment: You are breaking array bounds with `for (i = 0; i < WIDTH+1;i++)` causing *undefined behaviour* and from then on anything might happen. Ditto the height loop.

Comment: You also have `array[i-1][j] = 45` which is also *undefined behaviour* when `i == 0`. Similar problem the other end with `array[i+1][j]`

Comment: Please do not use magic numbers, instead of `45` use `'-'`, instead of `48` use `'0'` and so on.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have changed it to:

for (i = 0; i < WIDTH;i++) but the hyphens disappear all together. 

May I ask how does one fix the issue with: 

array[i-1][j] = 45 and how I end up with a negative array index if it's i = 0?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You cannot write to the "left" of an array. So you fix it with `if (i > 0) { array[i-1][j] = '-'; }`. You get a negative index when `i == 0` because `i-1` is `0-1` which is `-1`.